# TIMESAT input image requirement?

Tags: raster, ndvi

I tried to  work on TIMESAT but always facing a problem.
Here is the method I have used. Seems correct, but I get a warning at the end.

I have created a NDVI file from ENVI 4.8 >> Transform >> NDVI >> saved Output data type as Floating Point. Next I use Basic Tools >> Stretch Data >> Stretch Type Linear >> Stretch range by value -0.036 to 0.833 which is my NDVI range to Output DATA Range to 0 to 255. and saved the DATA Type as Integer as Timesat requires 8 bit integer(0-255).

I did the same procedure for my 5 NDVI files, except I used a different Stretch range by value X to Y, based on their own range.

Now I try to open them in TIMESAT >> TSM GUI, I created a txt file with the absolute path like these 5:

```
C:\timesat31\NDVI\trial\ndvi_1
C:\timesat31\NDVI\trial\ndvi_2
C:\timesat31\NDVI\trial\ndvi_3
C:\timesat31\NDVI\trial\ndvi_4
C:\timesat31\NDVI\trial\ndvi_5
```

They belong to 1 year data. 
Number of Row 1461 Number of Col 2255

Row to process 500 to 500

Column to process 500 to 500

but I get a following warning:

> Error while evaluating unicontrol Callback

Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

- make sure you are adding the file extension in the .txt file (e.g .img, .rst)
- make sure your files are in the right format accepted by  TIMESAT as suggested in the links below

[Getting image data into TIMESAT](http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/docs/Getting%20image%20data%20into%20TIMESAT.pdf)

[TIMESAT - File Formats](http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/timesat.asp?cat=5)

Answer (score 0):

Your input data process in Timesat seems to be alright, The error you're getting is mainly due to the number of images/year you have provided (in your case only 1 year).

**Try adding up images of 3 years or more**