# TIMESAT seasonality values different orders of magnitude

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, modis, timesat

I'm using TIMESAT 3.3 to find the seasonality parameters of a specific part of Ontario, using both the ASCII and image input methods. I've used the ASCII input method for specific points in the area, and the image input method for the overall area. However, the seasonality parameters I've derived from TSM_printseasons for both are wildly different. The ASCII input seasonality parameters are all between -1 and +1, while the image input parameters are in the thousands. Why are the values so different? Is there a difference in the scaling of the ASCII and image methods?

Comment: It looks like it's primarily an issue with null values.

Comment: Could you please explain the process regarding data conversion in ASCII format. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112133/timesat-input-image-requirement/298423#298423 Also check this link regarding input image requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the issue was with null values. When making the input files, the null values were set to -999, which greatly changed the values of the parameters. To solve this, I changed the valid data range in the TIMESAT settings file to -1 to 1.